# Creating A Batch File that Enables/Disables Write Protection of USB Drive

Tags: batch

I wanted to create a batch file that will enable or disable write protection. Basically, 2 batch files, one to enable and the other to disable write protection. I used to do it manually in CMD by using these commands.

Step 1: Start CMD In Administrater Mode

Step 2: Type Diskpart

Step 3: Type list volume

Step 4: Type select volume 5

Step 5: Type attributes volume set readonly OR attributes volume clear readonly

A batch file that does it will be much better but I have zero knowledge about that. I searched on the internet and managed to create a batch file that open up diskpart but couldn't go any further.

here's the code for that:

```
@ECHO OFF

Diskpart

PAUSE
```

Now, how do I make it to list volumes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using [diskpart scripts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart-scripts-and-examples). You would call `diskpart /s yourscript.txt`. You would type your commands into the script file like you normally would manually.

Depending on your familiarity with PowerShell, you would get better control using [PowerShell](https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2012/04/replace-diskpart-with-windows-powershell-basic-storage-cmdlets/) `Get-Disk` / `Get-Partition`